# csfv file reader - cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I'm trying to follow [this code](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/415732/Reading-and-Writing-CSV-Files-in-Csharp) for read write csv
but I'm getting **error on second constructor**

```
public class CsvFileReader : StreamReader
{
  public CsvFileReader(Stream stream)
    : base(stream)
  {
  }

  public CsvFileReader(string filename)
     : base(filename)
  {
  }
...
}
```

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to
>   'System.IO.Stream'

Comment: `public CsvFileWriter(Stream stream)
            : base(stream)`

Comment: second constructor is not stream, it's string filename?

Comment: Are you inherting a `System.IO.StreamWriter`? Show the declaration of your `CsvFileReader` class.

Comment: Should work fine, [StreamWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) accepts a string.

Comment: Yes, I'm referencing System.IO.StreamWriter. Now I'm confused.

Comment: What's your target Framework version? From the msdn documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.85).aspx), looks like the `StreamReader(string)` constructor was added in 4.0. I could be wrong, the site is a little wonky when trying to change the version you're viewing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your file bytes in `MemoryStream`

```
public class CsvFileReader : StreamReader
{
  public CsvFileReader(Stream stream)
    : base(stream)
  {
  }

  public CsvFileReader(string filename)
     : base(MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filename)))
  {
  }
...
}
```